# How to make clickable sprite-sheet?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a sprite-sheet `50px * 300px` which I want it to be clickable so it goes to three different pictures each pictures should have a variable A 1 2 and 3. meaning that when you click it goes to the second picture the variable  `myVar` should be `myVar=2;` and when you click it the third time `myVar` should be `myVar=3;` and so on think you .

Comment: can you provide some code snippets?

Answer (score 0):

```js
    var spriteSheetIndex = 0; // Using a 0-indexed variable is easier

    // Assuming you can split your sprites into 3 separate images
    var imageSources = [
        "https://emojipedia-us.s3.amazonaws.com/thumbs/120/apple/96/keycap-digit-one_31-fe0f-20e3.png",
        "https://emojipedia-us.s3.amazonaws.com/thumbs/120/apple/96/keycap-digit-two_32-fe0f-20e3.png",
        "https://emojipedia-us.s3.amazonaws.com/thumbs/120/apple/96/keycap-digit-three_33-fe0f-20e3.png",
    ]
    var imageAlts = ["image1", "image2", "image3"];
    function nextImage() {
        spriteSheetIndex = (spriteSheetIndex + 1) % 3;
        var spriteImage = document.getElementById("spritesheetimage");
        spriteImage.src = imageSources[spriteSheetIndex];
        spriteImage.alt = imageAlts[spriteSheetIndex];
    }
```

```html
    <img id="spritesheetimage"
     src="https://emojipedia-us.s3.amazonaws.com/thumbs/120/apple/96/keycap-digit-one_31-fe0f-20e3.png"
     alt="image1" height="100" width="100" onclick="nextImage()">
```

Comment: thank you for answering but my images are in one sprite sheet and there is an anrray for the click function .. myNumberArray [ 2 , 5 ,88]

Comment: Are 2, 5, and 88 indices for the images on the sprite sheet you want?

Comment: <style>
 body{
  background-color: gray;
 }
 #ball{
  height: 160px;
  width: 111px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background:url(image/ball.jpg)no-repeat;
  animation-play-state: paused;
 }

</style>
<script>
 var Myvar = 0;
ball.onclick function() {
    this.background-position:  -120px 0;
Myvar++;
}
</script>

<div id="ball"></div>

Comment: that is my code butt could not make onclick function work